# How did the team escape Lian Yu in Arrow

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, arrow

Why haven’t they explained how Arrow and his team escaped the island at end of season 5?

Throughout the whole of season 6 they haven’t mentioned anything about this.

Did I miss this being covered?

Comment: Are you asking how they survived the explosion or how did they get off the island? Getting off the island is not hard, it's been done *dozens* of times.

Comment: How they survived the explosion! They haven’t mentioned it at all

Answer (score 2):

Firstly..

> How did they escape the island?

By boat...

> Oliver: **There's an Argus supply ship on the eastern shore.**
>
> Felicity: That's on the other side of the island.
>
> Oliver: Slade knows where it is.

Secondly..

> How did they escape the explosions?

They took shelter in the crippled plane...mostly

> Curtis: What are we gonna do now?
>
> Diggle: What about the plane?
>
> Rene: Thought you said you couldn't get it fixed.
>
> Dinah: **For shielding us from the blast, - it should work just fine.**
>
> Quentin: It's not like there's a whole - lot of other options.

Of course, not everyone escaped unscathed but surviving doesn't really seem to have been that much of an issue.

Comment: Can't understand the downvotes - answer is correct and covers the question? Have an upvote.

Comment: Thanks...sometimes reasonable answers get bad responses. Meh! :)